# Set a stateful value and submit a form that needs that value at the same time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

This is an exerpt from a form that has a dropdown list of suggestions. I want the user to be able to click on a form suggestion and submit the form with the same click. The problem is that the form takes the value of `locationVal` when the user clicks, rather than the updated version. The updated version displays in the field, but the form has processed whatever the user had in the field before the click.

How can I make the form submission happen after the `locationVal` has been updated?

```
<ul >
  {autoCompleteValues.map((option, index) => (
    <li
      key={index}
      onClick={(e) => {
        setLocationVal(option);
        handleSubmit(e)
      }}
    >
      {option}
    </li>
  ))}
</ul>
```

The submit function

```
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (locationVal.length > 0) {
      const { latitude, longitude } = await getCityCoord(locationVal);
      query = {
        ...query,
        lat: latitude,
        lon: longitude,
        searchVal,
        locationVal,
        distance,
      };
    }
    query = { ...query, searchVal, offset: 0, distance };
    setQuery(query);
    setCurrentPageNum(1);
  };
```

The form should also be able to be submitted with the submit button. This is the first line of the form

```
<div onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using the [controlled](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) approach. Whatever values are editable via options on the screen, can be held in state.

Eventually, you have to use those values that you set it state, to display the contents of the drop down or text box etc as well as within the handleSubmit function.

Comment: While there is an onChange value for the dropdown, I cant have the entire form be controlled, because I am loading lots of images onSubmit. I cant make an API call for every keypress

Comment: You don't need to make an API call for every key press. You can control that aspect. Coming to the other point, if you want to execute an action only if something changed, then you can make the api call within `useEffect` hook and pass the dependencies to it, so it will take care of preventing the API call as per your needs.